# How to create sub folder in android studio

Tags: android

How to create user defined folder in Android studio for example to create mylayout folder in res folder and Also to create xml file same name as i created in layout folder. mean duplicate file I want to create xml file with the same name but the message show to that xml file must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, the only time you can create duplicate layout files is when they are within predefined folder names. res/layout-v14 for API 14+, res/layout-v21 for API 21+, etc and nowhere else.

Comment: thanks for information but i have only one layout folder in res i am using android studio and API 21